# How with jenssegers/mongodb get last Insert Id?

Tags: laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

On Laravel site using jenssegers/mongodb I have store method like :

```
public function store(ItemRequest $request)
{
    $request = request();
    try {
        $session = DB::getMongoClient()->startSession();
        $session->startTransaction();
        $insertData              = $request->all();
        $insertData['published'] = ! empty($insertData['published']);
        $item            = Item::create([
            'title'     => $insertData['title'],
            'text'      => $insertData['text'],
            'published' => $insertData['published'],
        ]);
        $session->commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $session->abortTransaction();
        return back()->withErrors(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }


    return redirect(route('admin.items.edit', $item->_id))
        ->with('message', 'New item was successfully added')
        ->with('message_type', 'success');
}
```

But making test for this controller method I did not find how to get ID on new ite, generated on mongodb site :

```
public function testIsItemEditFormSubmittedWithSuccess()
{
    $this->withoutMiddleware();
    $item = \App\Models\Item::factory(Item::class)->make();

    // Test Action
    $response = $this->actingAs(self::$loggedAdmin, 'web')->post(route('admin.items.store'), $item->toArray());

    $newItemId = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    // If to uncomment line above I got "Error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on null"
    $response->assertStatus(302);  // Redirection status
    $response->assertRedirect(route('admin.items.edit', [???])); // HOW can New ID on "store" method above ?
    $response->assertSessionHasNoErrors();
}
```

Any equvalent of lastInsertId for jenssegers/mongodb ?

```
"jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.9.2",
"laravel/framework": "^9.30.1",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check this issue.
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/2451

Your laravel should be 9.31. So downgrade it to 9.30 and wait next release.

Comment: Now in my composer.json I have :
  "laravel/framework": "^9.30.1"
  
and my phpstorm shows it as latest version.  
What have I to do ?

Change   it to

  "laravel/framework": "^9.30"
and run 
composer update

and which version have I to waite at https://github.com/laravel/framework ?

Comment: composer require "laravel/framework":"9.30.1"

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand  my phpstorm shows  "^9.30.1",  which is higher current laravel/framework at github. When I have to wait for new release ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo ^9.30.1 is meaning  9.3 >=  version  < 10.0

Comment: @PetroGromovo remove your vendor and composer.lock file and run composer install. Dont use composer update before new release